# Installation error

Tags: software-installation, dkms

I am new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu14.04 a few days back. Whenever i installed any program in Ubuntu Software Center.It shows me a message as `Package operation failed:The installation or removal of a software package failed` .

What does it mean?

It means software didn't install properly?

The error shown in the Details part is shown below:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite0.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 205852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsqlite0_2.8.17-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite0 (2.8.17-10ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-sqlite.
Preparing to unpack .../python-sqlite_1.0.1-11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-sqlite (1.0.1-11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-kaa-base.
Preparing to unpack .../python-kaa-base_0.6.0+svn4596-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-kaa-base (0.6.0+svn4596-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-kaa-metadata.
Preparing to unpack .../python-kaa-metadata_0.7.7+svn4596-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-kaa-metadata (0.7.7+svn4596-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-support.
Preparing to unpack .../python-support_1.0.15_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-support (1.0.15) ...
Selecting previously unselected package subdownloader.
Preparing to unpack .../subdownloader_2.0.14-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking subdownloader (2.0.14-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up hspa-modem-dkms (1.02.35) ...
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.02.35
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.02.35
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
dpkg: error processing package hspa-modem-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Setting up libsqlite0 (2.8.17-10ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python-sqlite (1.0.1-11) ...
Setting up python-kaa-base (0.6.0+svn4596-1) ...
Setting up python-kaa-metadata (0.7.7+svn4596-4) ...
Setting up python-support (1.0.15) ...
Setting up subdownloader (2.0.14-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
Error in function: 
Setting up hspa-modem-dkms (1.02.35) ...
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.02.35
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
Removing old hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.02.35
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new hspa-modem-1.02.35 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-34-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
dpkg: error processing package hspa-modem-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
```

Please can anyone tell me what is this?

Is this any problem or nothing?

Comment: Dont let the locale issues distract from the main problen, which is an error about DKMS. It says 'The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch.'

Comment: consider filing a bug report https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to set your locale.

```
sudo locale-gen en_IN en_IN.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

answer: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499826)

To deal with the DKMS issue (warning: this will remove your hspa-modem config):

```
sudo apt-get purge hspa-modem-dkms
sudo apt-get install hspa-modem-dkms
```

Of course, if you installed hspa-modem-dkms with dpkg then go ahead and install it the same way you did before.

Comment: still it shows same error..

Comment: @SureshC It needs to be set to en_IN.UTF-8. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I also tried your updated commands.But still it shows an error..pls help

Comment: @SureshC Use the command `locale -a` to list the available locales. Is your locale listed?

Comment: ya locale are listed as below.
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: @SureshC okay so are you getting a dkms error or a locales error or both

Comment: i am getting dkms error only..

Comment: @SureshC there you go. You will have to set up your configuration for hspa-modem again. If you still have a problem, you need to file a bug report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs